# How to uniquely identify a mobile device - asp.net

Tags: mobile, key, unique

I am trying to log certain actions of users in my database, and I need to retrieve the same actions once the user gets back to my site (unable to support cookies) after a few days, is there a way I can get any mobile device's ID and use that as a unique identifier?

The solution needs to be applicable for iPhone,iPad,iPod,Android,Nokia and other mobile devices.

Comment: This is *precisely* what cookies are for.  Why eschew them?

Comment: We are getting rid of cookies since some devices do not support them..

Comment: The main reason being we are also targeting devices that have cookies turned off by default

Comment: Then short of writing a custom mobile *app* for each platform, you're out of luck.  It would be a security violation for a unique mobile machine ID to be unwittingly sent to potentially hostile servers without the user's bidding.